# Setting datasource to new MatTable Data Source Angular 7

Tags: angular, datasource, mat-table

When I set my data source to an array and try to set the `dataSource` to a new mat table `dataSource` to be able to use filtering it comes with I get the error:

> Type 'MatTableDataSource' is missing the following properties from type 'TableRecord[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 24 more.

However, if I set the data source to any it works fine. Can someone please help me understand why:

**service.ts**

```
export interface PaginatedListResponse<TableRecord>{
  length: number,
  tableRows: Array<TableRecord>
}

export interface TableRecord{
  x: string,
  y: string,
  z: boolean,

}
```

**.ts**

```
dataSource: TableRecord[] = [];
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(response.tableRows);
//errror: Type 'MatTableDataSource<TableRecord>' is missing the following properties from type 'TableRecord[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 24 more.
```

**working example**

```
    dataSource: any;
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(response.tableRows);
   //No error
```

Comment: Any reason you're declaring dataSource as a ```TableRecord[]``` then immediately switching it to type ```MatTableDataSource```?

Comment: because the data is coming from the backend with pagination. So I am using an observable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The declaration for datasource is wrong. Do it like this:

```
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<TableRecord> = new MatTableDataSource([]) ;
```

Then, when you receive data from backend:

```
   this.dataSource.data = response.tableRows;
```

Comment: MatTable needs an object of the type MatTableDataSource or a simple array. Initially, you had defined an array of the type TableRecord, but tried to use that array as a MatTableDataSource. My change defined it as a MatTableDataSource. One of the properties a MatTableDataSource has is 'data', which is an array of the type you define. 'data' is always an array, that is why you omit [] in the typing for the datasource. You don't have to define 'new MatTableDataSource([])' right away - this is only if you want it assigned with an empty array in .data, instead of the entire object being undefined.